# OpenPGP encryption with BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption, openpgp

I have been trying to put together an in-memory public-key encryption infrastructure using OpenPGP via Bouncy Castle.  One of our vendors uses OpenPGP public key encryption to encrypt all their feeds, and requires us to do the same, so I'm stuck with the technology and the implementation.  So now I'm coding an OpenPGP encryption/ decryption toolkit for automating these feeds.

The examples at bouncycastle.org inexplicably default to writing encrypted data to and collecting keys from a file system; this is not what I want to do, so I've been trying to get everything stream-based.

I have gotten to the point where I can actually get my code to compile and run, but my encrypted payload is empty.  I think I'm missing something silly, but after several days of trying this and that, I have lost the ability to objectively examine this.

My utility class contains these methods:

```
    public static PgpPublicKey ImportPublicKey(
        this Stream publicIn)
    {
        var pubRings =
            new PgpPublicKeyRingBundle(PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(publicIn)).GetKeyRings().OfType<PgpPublicKeyRing>();
        var pubKeys = pubRings.SelectMany(x => x.GetPublicKeys().OfType<PgpPublicKey>());
        var pubKey = pubKeys.FirstOrDefault();
        return pubKey;
    }

    public static Stream Streamify(this string theString, Encoding encoding = null)
    {
        encoding = encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8;
        var stream = new MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(theString));
        return stream;
    }

    public static string Stringify(this Stream theStream,
                                   Encoding encoding = null)
    {
        encoding = encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(theStream, encoding))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    public static byte[] ReadFully(this Stream stream)
    {
        if (!stream.CanRead) throw new ArgumentException("This is not a readable stream.");
        var buffer = new byte[32768];
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (read <= 0)
                    return ms.ToArray();
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void PgpEncrypt(
        this Stream toEncrypt,
        Stream outStream,
        PgpPublicKey encryptionKey,
        bool armor = true,
        bool verify = true,
        CompressionAlgorithmTag compressionAlgorithm = CompressionAlgorithmTag.Zip)
    {
        if (armor) outStream = new ArmoredOutputStream(outStream);
        var compressor = new PgpCompressedDataGenerator(CompressionAlgorithmTag.Zip);
        outStream = compressor.Open(outStream);
        var data = toEncrypt.ReadFully();
        var encryptor = new PgpEncryptedDataGenerator(SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTag.Cast5, verify, new SecureRandom());
        encryptor.AddMethod(encryptionKey);
        outStream = encryptor.Open(outStream, data.Length);
        outStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
```

My test method looks like this:

```
    private static void EncryptMessage()
    {
        var pubKey = @"<public key text>";

        var clearText = "This is an encrypted message.  There are many like it but this one is cryptic.";
        using (var stream = pubKey.Streamify())
        {
            var key = stream.ImportPublicKey();
            using (var clearStream = clearText.Streamify())
            using (var cryptoStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                clearStream.PgpEncrypt(cryptoStream,key);
                cryptoStream.Position = 0;
                Console.WriteLine(cryptoStream.Stringify());
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The result I get looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: BCPG C# v1.7.4114.6378


Press any key to continue.
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

OK, I managed to get this working.  There were several problems with this implementation.  One problem was that certain things had to be done in order.  Here is what seems to need to happen:

- The raw data needs to be put into a `PgpLiteralData` object
- The literal data needs to be encrypted.
- The encrypted data needs to be compressed.
- The compressed data (optionally) needs to be armored.
- The underlying streams need to be closed in order of usage.

There should be a more elegant way to do this, but the streams used by the BouncyCastle library are all frustratingly one-way, and at several points, I needed to convert the stream to a byte array to get another part to work.  I include the code I used and independently verified; if someone has a verifyably better way of doing this, I would be quite interested.

```
public static class OpenPgpUtility
{
    public static void ExportKeyPair(
        Stream secretOut,
        Stream publicOut,
        AsymmetricKeyParameter publicKey,
        AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey,
        string identity,
        char[] passPhrase,
        bool armor)
    {
        if (armor)
        {
            secretOut = new ArmoredOutputStream(secretOut);
        }

        var secretKey = new PgpSecretKey(
            PgpSignature.DefaultCertification,
            PublicKeyAlgorithmTag.RsaGeneral,
            publicKey,
            privateKey,
            DateTime.UtcNow,
            identity,
            SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTag.Cast5,
            passPhrase,
            null,
            null,
            new SecureRandom()
            );

        secretKey.Encode(secretOut);

        if (armor)
        {
            secretOut.Close();
            publicOut = new ArmoredOutputStream(publicOut);
        }

        var key = secretKey.PublicKey;

        key.Encode(publicOut);

        if (armor)
        {
            publicOut.Close();
        }
    }

    public static PgpPublicKey ImportPublicKey(
        this Stream publicIn)
    {
        var pubRings =
            new PgpPublicKeyRingBundle(PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(publicIn)).GetKeyRings().OfType<PgpPublicKeyRing>();
        var pubKeys = pubRings.SelectMany(x => x.GetPublicKeys().OfType<PgpPublicKey>());
        var pubKey = pubKeys.FirstOrDefault();
        return pubKey;
    }

    public static PgpSecretKey ImportSecretKey(
        this Stream secretIn)
    {
        var secRings =
            new PgpSecretKeyRingBundle(PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(secretIn)).GetKeyRings().OfType<PgpSecretKeyRing>();
        var secKeys = secRings.SelectMany(x => x.GetSecretKeys().OfType<PgpSecretKey>());
        var secKey = secKeys.FirstOrDefault();
        return secKey;
    }

    public static Stream Streamify(this string theString, Encoding encoding = null)
    {
        encoding = encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8;
        var stream = new MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(theString));
        return stream;
    }

    public static string Stringify(this Stream theStream,
                                   Encoding encoding = null)
    {
        encoding = encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(theStream, encoding))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    public static byte[] ReadFully(this Stream stream, int position = 0)
    {
        if (!stream.CanRead) throw new ArgumentException("This is not a readable stream.");
        if (stream.CanSeek) stream.Position = 0;
        var buffer = new byte[32768];
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (read <= 0)
                    return ms.ToArray();
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void PgpEncrypt(
        this Stream toEncrypt,
        Stream outStream,
        PgpPublicKey encryptionKey,
        bool armor = true,
        bool verify = false,
        CompressionAlgorithmTag compressionAlgorithm = CompressionAlgorithmTag.Zip)
    {
        var encryptor = new PgpEncryptedDataGenerator(SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTag.Cast5, verify, new SecureRandom());
        var literalizer = new PgpLiteralDataGenerator();
        var compressor = new PgpCompressedDataGenerator(compressionAlgorithm);
        encryptor.AddMethod(encryptionKey);

        //it would be nice if these streams were read/write, and supported seeking.  Since they are not,
        //we need to shunt the data to a read/write stream so that we can control the flow of data as
        //we go.
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) // this is the read/write stream
        using (var armoredStream = armor ? new ArmoredOutputStream(stream) : stream as Stream)
        using (var compressedStream = compressor.Open(armoredStream))
        {
            //data is encrypted first, then compressed, but because of the one-way nature of these streams,
            //other "interim" streams are required.  The raw data is encapsulated in a "Literal" PGP object.
            var rawData = toEncrypt.ReadFully();
            var buffer = new byte[1024];
            using (var literalOut = new MemoryStream())
            using (var literalStream = literalizer.Open(literalOut, 'b', "STREAM", DateTime.UtcNow, buffer))
            {
                literalStream.Write(rawData, 0, rawData.Length);
                literalStream.Close();
                var literalData = literalOut.ReadFully();

                //The literal data object is then encrypted, which flows into the compressing stream and
                //(optionally) into the ASCII armoring stream.
                using (var encryptedStream = encryptor.Open(compressedStream, literalData.Length))
                {
                    encryptedStream.Write(literalData, 0, literalData.Length);
                    encryptedStream.Close();
                    compressedStream.Close();
                    armoredStream.Close();

                    //the stream processes are now complete, and our read/write stream is now populated with 
                    //encrypted data.  Convert the stream to a byte array and write to the out stream.
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    var data = stream.ReadFully();
                    outStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My test method looked like this:

```
    private static void EncryptMessage()
    {
        var pubKey = @"<public key text here>";

        var clearText = @"<message text here>";
        using (var stream = pubKey.Streamify())
        {
            var key = stream.ImportPublicKey();
            using (var clearStream = clearText.Streamify())
            using (var cryptoStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                clearStream.PgpEncrypt(cryptoStream, key);
                cryptoStream.Position = 0;
                var cryptoString = cryptoStream.Stringify();
                Console.WriteLine(cryptoString);
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Since someone asked, my decryption algorithm looked like this:

```
public static Stream PgpDecrypt(
    this Stream encryptedData,
    string armoredPrivateKey,
    string privateKeyPassword,
    Encoding armorEncoding = null)
{
    armorEncoding = armorEncoding ?? Encoding.UTF8;
    var stream = PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(encryptedData);
    var layeredStreams = new List<Stream> { stream }; //this is to clean up/ dispose of any layered streams.
    var dataObjectFactory = new PgpObjectFactory(stream);
    var dataObject = dataObjectFactory.NextPgpObject();
    Dictionary<long, PgpSecretKey> secretKeys;

    using (var privateKeyStream = armoredPrivateKey.Streamify(armorEncoding))
    {
        var secRings =
            new PgpSecretKeyRingBundle(PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(privateKeyStream)).GetKeyRings()
                                                                                       .OfType<PgpSecretKeyRing>();
        var pgpSecretKeyRings = secRings as PgpSecretKeyRing[] ?? secRings.ToArray();
        if (!pgpSecretKeyRings.Any()) throw new ArgumentException("No secret keys found.");
        secretKeys = pgpSecretKeyRings.SelectMany(x => x.GetSecretKeys().OfType<PgpSecretKey>())
                                      .ToDictionary(key => key.KeyId, value => value);
    }

    while (!(dataObject is PgpLiteralData) && dataObject != null)
    {
        try
        {
            var compressedData = dataObject as PgpCompressedData;
            var listedData = dataObject as PgpEncryptedDataList;

            //strip away the compression stream
            if (compressedData != null)
            {
                stream = compressedData.GetDataStream();
                layeredStreams.Add(stream);
                dataObjectFactory = new PgpObjectFactory(stream);
            }

            //strip the PgpEncryptedDataList
            if (listedData != null)
            {
                var encryptedDataList = listedData.GetEncryptedDataObjects()
                                                  .OfType<PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData>().First();
                var decryptionKey = secretKeys[encryptedDataList.KeyId]
                    .ExtractPrivateKey(privateKeyPassword.ToCharArray());
                stream = encryptedDataList.GetDataStream(decryptionKey);
                layeredStreams.Add(stream);
                dataObjectFactory = new PgpObjectFactory(stream);
            }

            dataObject = dataObjectFactory.NextPgpObject();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log exception here.
            throw new PgpException("Failed to strip encapsulating streams.", ex);
        }
    }

    foreach (var layeredStream in layeredStreams)
    {
        layeredStream.Close();
        layeredStream.Dispose();
    }

    if (dataObject == null) return null;

    var literalData = (PgpLiteralData)dataObject;
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    using (var clearData = literalData.GetInputStream())
    {
        Streams.PipeAll(clearData, ms);
    }
    ms.Position = 0;
    return ms;
}
```

Comment: I was looking at Bouncy castle and came across this post, one question I have is is there a way to remove the PGP marker from the encrypted string?

Comment: @katie77 I believe if you unwrap it properly (using the layered streams) the marker gets properly stripped off.

Comment: Thanks for this, this is the only code I've found that actually works for PGP encryption/decryption.

Comment: Compressing encrypted data makes little sense. Are you sure of the sequence (not in the code, but in the items you listed)?

Comment: @ajeh Hah you're asking me about something I wrote over 4 years ago, so I'm not 100% sure any more, but I recall I felt the same way and tried to compress, then encrypt, with no success.  With the absolutely atrocious documentation for this library, my main concern was to get this working... and this works.  YMMV, please feel free to experiment and post results.  I do not claim that this is the best way, just the only way that worked for me.

Comment: I share the sentiment about documentation. Ended up encrypting the zipped files in the end and not going back to re-visit.

Comment: Ancient posting, BUT....

As others have pointed out, there is no point in compressing AFTER encryption.  That will simply cause the output file to grow rather than shrink.

As for as a sample that works, there is this (and it DOES compress THEN encrypt): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209291/pgp-encrypt-and-decrypt

Note that it does still use MemoryStream, which imposes practical limits on the size of the file that can be encrypted.  Unfortunately the Bouncy library does not appear to support a compress/encrypt solution which avoids MemoryStream without resorting  to temp files.

Comment: Excellent @Larry, thanks for that.  That was something that always bugged me.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs you might find my recent answer to referenced posting above question of interest:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209291/pgp-encrypt-and-decrypt/58158381#58158381